# Sulphonation of benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics, hydrocarbons

Will nitrobenzene and benzene have the same rate towards sulphonation reaction, since the formation of sigma complex is not the RDS of this reaction?

Answer (score -1):

**Nitrobenzene and benzene would NOT have the same rate towards any type of electrophilic substitution reaction as strength of nucleophile - (nitro)benzene does matter.**

Nitro group as in nitrobenzene is highly deactivating group due its electron withdrawing nature and therefore decreases the nucleophilicity of benzene ring.

[image: Sulphonation Rate Constants]

[IJOART_document](http://www.ijoart.org/docs/Aromatic-Sulphonation-and-Related-Reactions.pdf)

Comment: But how shall it matter in "SULPHONATION" if the attack of electrophile, and thus the formation of sigma complex, is NOT the rds of sulphonation?

Comment: @Anonymous : Read the document... It is very well written and presented

Comment: @Mithoron : Should I not capitalise compound names in order to make them stand out and increase the readers' attention towards them?

Comment: I don't think it should be used for emphasis, also using emphasising in multiple ways at once tends to be too much.

Comment: @Mithoron : Your reputations speak up for your experience in answering on this interface. I'll try to follow your advice since it seems (highly) logical.